# csv to json in python

Tags: python, json, csv

Hey so I have some hash ids in a csv file like

XbRPhe65YbC+xtgGQ8ukeZEr9xFOC4MEs9Z0wUidGSec=
XbRPhe65YbC+xtgGQ8uksrqSUJ/HhTPj1d2pL0/vuGrHM=

and I want to parse them into python wrap them in some additional code like

{"id" :"XbRPshe65YbC+xtGQ8ukqR2u2btfNeNe2gtcs72QbxPA=", "timestamp":"20150831"},

and then wrap all of that in some JSON syntax. This is then sent as a post request. Problem is I cannot seem to make it JSON readable. Everything seems to be ordered wrong and I am getting extra \.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

df=pd.read_csv('test.csv',sep=',',header=None)
df[0] = '{"id" :"' + df[0].astype(str) + '", "timestamp":"20150831"}, ' 

df = df[:-1] # removes last comma


test = 'hello'
data =[ { "ids":[ df[0]],
          "attributes":[
                {
                "name":"girl"
                },
                {
                "name":"size"
                }
                ]
        }
        ]

json1 = data.to_json()
print(json1)
```

Comment: Have you considered using the `csv` and `json` modules to do this? Pandas seems like overkill for what you're doing here, and `json` would allow you format things nicely in your output.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: How about links to the modules instead... [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that pandas doesn't seem to be the simplest tool for the job here. The built-in libraries will work great:

```
import csv
import json

with open('test.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    data = {
        "ids": [{"id": row[0], "timestamp": "20150831"} for row in csvreader],
        "attributes": [
            {"name": "girl"},
            {"name": "size"}
        ]
    }

json1 = json.dumps(data)
print(json1)
```

Comment: You haven't indented your code properly. It's raising `ValueError`.

Comment: Thanks Peter, although now I am getting ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. From a quick google looks like it doesnt like the indentation of for. Any thoughts?

Comment: @tosh, the problem is that the definition of `data` should fall under the `with` block (indent those lines to match the `csvreader = ...` line). Also, if you change the call to `json.dumps` to read `json1 = json.dumps(data, indent=4)`, it will pretty print the json for you with indentation. Finally, you probably want to add a check to the list comprehension to make sure the row isn't empty, otherwise you'll be indexing out of range.

Comment: Fixed indentation for you, should have realised the csvreader would need the open file :-)